# Dialogflow is not detecting entity when input is not exactly the same as training phrase?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've made an intent to detect user's answer when they say, for example "when shop is closed" where "closed" is an entity.

When I give the input exactly the same as my training phrase, "when shop is closed", everything is working as expected and and dialogflow correctly detected the intent and the entity value (as shown in the second screenshot).

However, when I input a slight variant to the training phrase, by adding extra words "I think" in front of the sentence, dialogflow still correctly detected the intent, but however this time the parameter value is empty. (as shown in first screenshot)

I will need the value to be detected in both cases, and can't figure out why this is happening.

Screenshot 1
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2
[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

Google has published best practices for conversation design here, which should help:

https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/basics

In this case, have you tried adding, "When is the shop closed?" as a training phrase? Clarifying verb tenses and sentence structure might help Dialogflow correctly identify the parameters you're hoping to extract from a user's given intent.